# All content over HTTP once authenticated with Identity 2 - safe to do?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, security, asp.net-identity

I am using OWIN Identity 2 in my MVC application to perform authentication. This is performed over HTTPS.

My question is, once the user has successfully authenticated, is there any reason to keep them on HTTPS, or from a security point of view is it quite OK to put them back to HTTP assuming there are no more sensitive details being transferred?

I am unsure of exactly what is transferred between client and server for each request when using Identity 2, so wanted to check here first.

Comment: Is there any good reason *NOT* to keep them on https?

Comment: Good point. I assumed that it's all extra overhead on the site.

Comment: @LaurenceFrost extra overhead is a myth. Modern hardware won't even think about SSL. I recommend keep all traffic HTTPS in all cases. Here is an article about SSL "overhead" https://www.maxcdn.com/blog/ssl-performance-myth/

Comment: @trailmax great article. Many thanks for the link.

Answer (score 1):

If you are transporting anything sensitive in the request you should use HTTPS (transport layer security).

And the authentication cookie from Identity 2 is considered sensitive information.

Not to mention, when you do not use HTTPS, you are opening your website to passive and active traffic sniffing and Man-In-The-Middle-Attacks.

I suggest you look at and become familiar with OWASP Top 10: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Top_10_2013-Top_10

This is a non-profict organization that is focused on improving the security of software.

If you want additional information, I highly recommend taking some courses by [Troy Hunt](http://www.troyhunt.com) on [PluralSight.com](https://www.pluralsight.com/authors/troy-hunt)

Comment: Thank you - some bedtime reading for tonight before implementing anything. I shall report back tomorrow...